# How to specify spaCy to recognize a sentence based on full stop

Tags: python, spacy

I had the following text

```
text = 'Shop 1 942.10 984.50 1023.90 1064.80 \n\nShop 2 first 12 months 1032.70 1079.10 1122.30 1167.20 \n\nShop 2 after 12 months 1045.50 1092.60 1136.30 1181.70 \n\nShop 3 1059.40 1107.10 1151.40 1197.40 \n\nShop 4 first 3 months 1072.60 1120.90 1165.70 1212.30 \n\nShop 4 after 3 months 1082.40 1131.10 1176.40 1223.40'
```

Which I cleaned up by replacing `\n\n` with `'. '` with this code

```
text = text.replace('\n\n', '. ')
```

I constructed a `matcher` with a simple and generic pattern like this

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg',  disable=['ner'])
doc = nlp(text)
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [{'ORTH': 'Shop'}, {'LIKE_NUM': True}] 
matcher.add('REV', None, pattern)
```

I then used the `matcher` to find all the *sentences* which were separated in the text by the full stop `.`

```
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    matched_span = doc[start:end]
    print(matched_span.text)         
    print(matched_span.sent, '\n')
```

I expected to obtain these results:

```
Shop 1
Shop 1 942.10 984.50 1023.90 1064.80 . 

Shop 2
Shop 2 first 12 months 1032.70 1079.10 1122.30 1167.20 . 

Shop 2
Shop 2 after 12 months 1045.50 1092.60 1136.30 1181.70 . 

Shop 3
Shop 3 1059.40 1107.10 1151.40 1197.40 . 

Shop 4
Shop 4 first 3 months 1072.60 1120.90 1165.70 1212.30 . 

Shop 4
Shop 4 after 3 months 1082.40 1131.10 1176.40 1223.40
```

However, due to the way spaCy processed the `text`, it didn't split the `sentences` by the full stop `.` but instead by some *opaque* rules that I don't know what they are, my code returned the following results

```
Shop 1
Shop 1 942.10 

Shop 2
Shop 2 first 12 months 

Shop 2
Shop 2 after 12 months 1045.50 1092.60 

Shop 3
Shop 3 

Shop 4
Shop 4 first 3 months 

Shop 4
Shop 4 after 3 months
```

Is there a way to instruct/override spaCy how to *recognize* a sentence in a text based on a specific pattern (full stop `.` in this case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want to do is define a custom sentence segmentizer.  The default sentence segmentizing algorithm spaCy employs uses a dependency tree to attempt to figure out where sentences begin and end.  You can override this by making your own function that defines sentence boundaries and adding it to the NLP pipeline.  Following [the example in spaCy's documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#component-example1):

```
import spacy

def custom_sentencizer(doc):
    ''' Look for sentence start tokens by scanning for periods only. '''
    for i, token in enumerate(doc[:-2]):  # The last token cannot start a sentence
        if token.text == ".":
            doc[i+1].is_sent_start = True
        else:
            doc[i+1].is_sent_start = False  # Tell the default sentencizer to ignore this token
    return doc

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg',  disable=['ner'])
nlp.add_pipe(custom_sentencizer, before="parser")  # Insert before the parser can build its own sentences
# text = ...
doc = nlp(text)

matcher = spacy.matcher.Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [{'ORTH': 'Shop'}, {'LIKE_NUM': True}] 
matcher.add('REV', None, pattern)

matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    matched_span = nlp(text2)[start:end]
    print(matched_span.text)         
    print(matched_span.sent, '\n')

# Shop 1
# Shop 1 942.10 984.50 1023.90 1064.80 .
# 
# Shop 2
# Shop 2 first 12 months 1032.70 1079.10 1122.30 1167.20 .
# 
# Shop 2
# Shop 2 after 12 months 1045.50 1092.60 1136.30 1181.70 .
# 
# Shop 3
# Shop 3 1059.40 1107.10 1151.40 1197.40 .
# 
# Shop 4
# Shop 4 first 3 months 1072.60 1120.90 1165.70 1212.30 .
# 
# Shop 4
# Shop 4 after 3 months 1082.40 1131.10 1176.40 1223.40
```

Your text is very different from natural language, so it's no wonder spaCy doesn't do a great job.  Its internal models are trained on examples that look explicitly like text you would read in a book or on the Internet, while your example looks more like machine-readable lists of numbers.  For instance, if the text you used were written out more like prose, it might look something like this:

> Shop 1's numbers were 942.10, 984.50, 1023.90, and 1064.80.  Shop 2, for the first 12 months, had numbers 1032.70, 1079.10, 1122.30, and 1167.20.  Shop 2, after 12 months, had 1045.50, 1092.60, 1136.30, and 1181.70.  Shop 3: 1059.40, 1107.10, 1151.40, and 1197.40.  Shop 4 in the first 3 months had numbers 1072.60, 1120.90, 1165.70, and 1212.30.  After 3 months, Shop 4 had 1082.40, 1131.10, 1176.40, and 1223.40.

Using this as the input gives spaCy's default parser a much better chance at figuring out where the sentence breaks are, even with all those other punctuation marks:

```
text2 = "Shop 1's numbers were 942.10, 984.50, 1023.90, and 1064.80.  Shop 2, for the first 12 months, had numbers 1032.70, 1079.10, 1122.30, and 1167.20.  Shop 2, after 12 months, had 1045.50, 1092.60, 1136.30, and 1181.70.  Shop 3: 1059.40, 1107.10, 1151.40, and 1197.40.  Shop 4 in the first 3 months had numbers 1072.60, 1120.90, 1165.70, and 1212.30.  After 3 months, Shop 4 had 1082.40, 1131.10, 1176.40, and 1223.40."

nlp2 = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg',  disable=['ner'])  # default sentencizer
doc2 = nlp2(text2)
matches2 = matcher(doc2)  # same matcher
for match_id, start, end in matches2:
    matched_span = nlp2(text2)[start:end]
    print(matched_span.text)
    print(matched_span.sent, '\n')

# Shop 1
# Shop 1's numbers were 942.10, 984.50, 1023.90, and 1064.80.
#
# Shop 2
# Shop 2, for the first 12 months, had numbers 1032.70, 1079.10, 1122.30, and 1167.20.
#
# Shop 2
# Shop 2, after 12 months, had 1045.50, 1092.60, 1136.30, and 1181.70.
#
# Shop 3
# Shop 3: 1059.40, 1107.10, 1151.40, and 1197.40.
#
# Shop 4
# Shop 4 in the first 3 months had numbers 1072.60, 1120.90, 1165.70, and 1212.30.
#
# Shop 4
# After 3 months, Shop 4 had 1082.40, 1131.10, 1176.40, and 1223.40.
```

Note that this is not fool-proof, and the default parser will still mess up if the sentence structure gets too complex or fancy.  NLP in general, and spaCy in particular, is not about parsing a small data set to extract particular values exactly right every time:  it's more about parsing gigabytes of documents quickly and doing a good enough job in a statistical sense to perform meaningful computations on the data.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed and clear explanation, @PasTE! A part from showing me how to segmenting custom sentences, you also gave me other insights about the data I'm working with and the overview evaluation of spaCy in your last paragraph. By the way, the reason for `doc[:-2]` was to ignore the space and the period ` .` at the end of the `doc`?

Comment: `doc[:-2]` creates a Span containing all but the last two Tokens from the Document `doc`.  The way the algorithm written in the spaCy example works is to look at the Token at location `i`, then use that to decide if Token `i+1` _begins_ a sentence.  This algorithm assumes that a single Token cannot both begin and end a sentence, therefore the last Token can't begin a sentence, therefore the second-to-last Token does not need to be checked.  Nothing special about the Document:  just a little optimization.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Having time to think about it, do you think I should make a little change in the function like this `def custom_sentencizer(text): doc = nlp(text) for i, token in enumerate(doc[:-2]):...` to prevent the case where user might assume `doc` is just the raw text they want to split with the `custom_sentenizer`?

Comment: I would make that clear in the documentation or perform a check and throw an exception rather than attempting the conversion in the sentencizer itself.  The parsing of text into a document is (a) not an inexpensive process, and (b) may cause an infinite recursion if `custom_sentencizer` is a part of spaCy's pipeline.